# How to attack CSRF to JSF application

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, csrf

I am developing application using JSF2.0 & Richfaces3.3.3 with tomcat.
Most of the site and user told 'JSF2.0 built-in CSRF support'...
How **i test " my application prevent CSRF attack or not "**

In my application, i have one login page and after login and navigate to content page.
The content page i divide 4 parts such as top, bottom, left, and right panel.
I include the jsp pages into the right panel (dynamically) depends upon the ajax request.
In my every action, just reRender to the right panel.

Help me..
Thanks inadvance

Comment: Testing is easy if you **understand** what CSRF is. You don't seem to understand at all what CSRF is.

Answer (score 1):

OWASP has a [full page answer](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_CSRF_%28OWASP-SM-005%29) to this question.  IN a nutshell, you capture/create a URL that updates something (change POST to GET to grab the parameters).  Then you enter that URL without being in the application and see if it works.  If it does, you haven't protected against CSRF/